# How to override some of ajax based picker logic?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Alfresco Community v5.2 (other versions too) includes some of preconfigured workflows that available on the page `/share/page/start-workflow`

I'm interested in *"Review and Approve (one or more reviewers) - Assign a review task to multiple reviewers"*.

Actually, to be more precise - in the logic of assigning.

For example, I want to make some customization - [Customization of the user task screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537097/customization-of-the-user-task-screen)

I want to display members in the table, not in the list. For this I need to understand how they appear in the list.

In the file `share-config-custom.xml` I can find the path to the templates.

For example, for the `bpm:workflowDueDate` it will be:

```
...
<field id="bpm:workflowDueDate" set="info" label-id="workflow.field.due">
  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/info.ftl" />
</field>
...
```

But for `bpm:assignees` the template is not specified:

```
...
<field id="bpm:assignee" label-id="workflow.field.reviewer" set="assignee" />
...
```

I assume, that there are some back-end beans, that perform most of the logic.

How can I override some of ajax based picker logic?

Comment: What ajax logic you want to change ? or you want to override people picker search ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a form control is not provided in the share form config, Alfresco Share falls back to some defaults depending on the type of the field.

[bpm:assignee is an association](https://github.com/Alfresco/community-edition-old/blob/master/projects/repository/config/alfresco/model/bpmModel.xml#L405) to a person node, so I would expect it to point by default to `association.ftl` !

What I suggest is to copy that file into a new one let's say `src/main/amp/alfresco/site-webscripts/${project.groupId}/form/controls/custom-association.ftl`

and then in your `share-config-custom.xml` copy over the form config for the task with one small update :

```
...
<field id="bpm:assignee" label-id="workflow.field.reviewer" set="assignee" >
  <control template="/${project.groupId}/form/controls/custom-association.ftl" />
</field>
...
```

and then you can safely fiddle with `custom-association.ftl` because it is almost never a good idea to override alfresco defaults !

---

**UPDATE :** The value of that control is a list of nodeRefs referring to the nodes of the selected users. It is the ObjectFinder Java script object who is managing things behind the scene, calling a special endpoint to fetch all sort of data to be shown, then manipulates the DOM accordingly ! You might want to look at [object-finder.js](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/webapp/components/object-finder/object-finder.js) and [picker.inc.ftl](https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/common/picker.inc.ftl)

Comment: The value of that control is a list of nodeRefs referring to the nodes of the selected users. it is the ObjectFinder Java script object who does call a special endpoint to fetch all sort of data to be shown, then manipulates the dom accordingly ! You might want to look at https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/webapp/components/object-finder/object-finder.js and  https://github.com/Alfresco/share/blob/master/web-framework-commons/src/main/resources/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/common/picker.inc.ftl